# how to use string doesn't starts with in groovy

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I want to write a condition in groovy where branch name should not be equal to develop and should not start with release. I have tried below code. Please help to fix it.

```
if ("${BRANCH_NAME}"!="develop" ||! ("${BRANCH_NAME}".startsWith("release")))
        {
        properties(
        [
    buildDiscarder(logRotator(daysToKeepStr: '60', numToKeepStr: '7')),
        ]
                  )
        }
```

Comment: Your code is very hard to read the way it is indented. Does the code you posted generate an error? If so, please include it in your question. Is that trailing comma valid syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primary issue:
You're using OR instead of AND. This means both conditions must be simultaniously true to avoid going into the code block. Where I think you really want, if either are true, skip.

I also changed just general syntax. GString is unnecessary, theres no need to do string interpolation if its just 1 variable. And strings dont need to be GString if there are no variables. So removed the quotes for branch name, and converted the others to regular strings (single quote)

Just also a note, I dont think you should wrap your entire pipeline in this if statement. Its probably fine to have your properties outside and just block logic execution.

```
#!groovy

if (env.BRANCH_NAME != 'develop' && !(env.BRANCH_NAME).startsWith('release')) {
    properties([
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(daysToKeepStr: '60', numToKeepStr: '7')),
    ])
    echo 'here'
}
```